# indexação vs geração de página com PHP

Tags: php, google

Tenho alguns produtos e todas as informações deles estão armazenadas no banco de dados.
Quando algum cliente seleciona algum produto, é enviado via `POST` o `ID` do produto e assim é gerada uma nova página com o produto.

E isso indexa no Google? A URL é algo assim:

> site.com/produtos/vestido-manga-curta

Onde `vestido-manga-curta` na verdade era um `GET` na `URL` que foi reescrita para não ficar algo como:

> site.com/produtos?produto=vestido%20manga%20curta.

A página `produtos.php` ali ela cuida de receber a `ID` e gerar a nova página(com as informações do produto..)

Estou receoso com isso, preciso clarear as ideias..

Comment: A melhor maneira de indexar suas páginas nos motores de busca é utilizando URLs amigáveis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma URL amigável precisa não somente ser amigável para ser bem posicionada numa pesquisa, mas sim possuir a `keyword` (chave/palavra de busca). Então o modo como você recupera o conteúdo da página e o apresenta/manipula* é indiferente pro Google. Veja esse caso real abaixo:

[image: Demonstração keyword]

Embora o Google não posicione ou tire posições de seu site com base na sua URL, uma URL bem descritiva atrai mais cliques, e o [CTR (taxa de cliques)](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Click-through_rate) é um critério para a avaliação de um site, então: 
`url descritiva > mais pessoas vêem meu site > melhor meu site é posicionado`.

Pra ajudar também veja essa imagem que mostra como uma url deve ser estruturada.

[image: Cheat seed url SEO]

Comment: obrigado Edu! perfeito, gostei do gráfico.